# Pesonalização de Campo Login no Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identity

Pessoal Uma dúvida que por mais que seja aparentemente boba não encontrei em nenhum artigo que fala do Identity. Como posso customizar as características de autenticação para ao invés de usar o e-mail como nome do usuário usar outro atributo personalizado como um campo de nome "**login**" e combiná-lo com a senha que já vem no template?...

Answer (score 0):

Quando você adicionar o identity: "services.AddIdentity", você pode passar suas classes customizadas, por exemplo, a do usuário:

```
services.AddIdentity<UsuarioCustomizado>();
```

O UsuarioCustomizado deve herdar a classe IdentityUser, então você adiciona os campos customizados, no caso, eu adicionei o CPF:

```
 public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string CPF { get; set; }
}
```

Agora para você customizar no banco de dados como a chaves, usando o EF Core, você pode criar um context herdando IdentityDbContext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
     : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityTypeConfiguration());
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

E finalmente no OnModelCreating você pode alterar as configurações das tabelas.

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2